# Access key for textbox in knock out

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using my knock out for my html controls

```
<!-- ko foreach: myMode().tasks -->
<input class="txtbox-size" type="text" data-bind="value: taskname" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

I need to set the access key for the first text box alone. When i try to add it in doucument.ready

```
       var Target = $('.txtbox-size:first');
```

and tried to set attribute for Target but it is getting applied to all text boxes. Anybody could tell me why it is happening. Is there any way in ko to set the access key for the first textbox alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$index` object to detect first tag and then use `attr` binding:

```
<!-- ko foreach: myMode().tasks -->
<input type="text" data-bind="value: taskname, attr: { accesskey: $index() == 0? 'Your Access Key': ''}"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Artem was close, but I think, because this is an html attribute for which knockout does not have native support, you'll have to use [`attr`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

```
<!-- ko foreach: myMode().tasks -->
<input type="text" data-bind="value: taskname, attr: { 'accesskey': $index() == 0? 'Your Access Key': '' }"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```